# Drupal 7 OR condition with a series of AND condition

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, query-builder, or-condition

I have a `Drupal query like below

```
$qry = db_select('table1', 't1');
$qry->addField('t1','etid','entity_id');
$qry->join('node', 'n FORCE INDEX(field1)', 'n.nid = t1.etid');
$qry->join('table2','t2','n.nid = t2.entity_id');
$qry->join('table3','t3','t3.sid=t2.field2');
$qry->condition('t3.field', 'yes', '=');
$qry->condition('n.field', '<value>', 'LIKE');
$qry->condition('t1.field', '<id>', '=');
$qry->condition('n.field', '<value>', '=');
$qry->condition('n.field', <value>, '=');
$qry->condition('t1.field', '<vlaue>', '=');
$qry->orderBy('t1.field','DESC');
$qry->range(0,300);
```

I would like to add an `OR` condition to this query. So it will be a global `OR` condition.

I added a code like below

```
$or = db_or();
$or->condition('t1.field', [123,456], 'IN');
$qry->condition($or);
```

But it didn't add an `OR` condition but put the condition query within braces in an `AND` condition.

**How can I achieve an output query like**

```
where field = value and field = value and field = value OR field = value
```

**by using Drupal query builder**? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [db_and](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_and/7.x)

```
$db_and = db_and();


$qry = db_select('table1', 't1');
$qry->addField('t1','etid','entity_id');
$qry->join('node', 'n FORCE INDEX(field1)', 'n.nid = t1.etid');
$qry->join('table2','t2','n.nid = t2.entity_id');
$qry->join('table3','t3','t3.sid=t2.field2');

$db_and->condition('t3.field', 'yes', '=');
$db_and->condition('n.field', '<value>', 'LIKE');
$db_and->condition('t1.field', '<id>', '=');
$db_and->condition('n.field', '<value>', '=');
$db_and->condition('n.field', <value>, '=');
$db_and->condition('t1.field', '<vlaue>', '=');

$or = db_or();
$or->condition('t1.field', [123,456], 'IN');
$or->condition($db_and);

$qry->condition($or);

$qry->orderBy('t1.field','DESC');
$qry->range(0,300);
```